# How to set the old-style build log as a default build error view in XCode 4

Tags: c++, ios, xcode4

XCode 4 has the new build errors panel, that doesn't work at all for us. We have template-heavy C++ library, which might be the reason that XCode 4 is working so badly.

It shows old errors after a recompilation, which makes it really painful to use. It also doesn't allow quick access to see full error messages. The old build log didn't have these problems. It is still accessible from the right most small icon, but we'd like to use it as our default build error view. Is it possible to configure XCode 4 to use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer myself. Xcode 4 Behaviors allows you to customize compilation behavior quite nicely.

1. Go to Preferences -> Behaviors -> Build starts
2. Enable: "Show" navigator "Log Navigator"
3. Enable: Navigate to "current log"